# json view \n as newline in browser

Tags: firefox, browser, json

I've been looking around but every answer I found seems to be close but not accurate.
I have a json returned by an web api ("content-type: application/json" in response header) that has newlines in quotation marks, say:

```
{"id": {
    "type": "int(x=0) -> integer\nint(x, base=10) -> integer\n\nConvert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments"
    }
}
```

How do I make Firefox (or any other browser) to actually start a new line if it encouners \n while showing raw json in its window?